# Cant figure out what these errors happening on my webstore? Anyone help, posting the error content

Tags: security, shopify

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFWoG.png)

No idea whats going with these errors code, i dont understand why is it saying anonymous and its giving me security concerns

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, those are warnings (not errors).  Nothing is broken, but some things may be running sub-optimally.  The alerts are noting that the code on your site is preloading a number of assets but not using them right away.  This may indicate that your site is unnecessarily using priority resources to bring those resources in.

Beneath the warning message, you are seeing what is known as a "call stack" - it's the chain of functions that have been called to get to the point that resulted in that warning message. There are two kinds of functions in Javascript: named functions and anonymous functions.

Named functions are what you might normally think of as a function.  You declare it with something like:

```
function doSomething(parameter){
  // Some awesome code here
}
```

And later call it as:

```
doSomething(some_input);
```

However, in Javascript we can also create un-named, aka anonymous, functions in-line.  This is often done for 'callback' functions, or functions that serve as a part B to the main function's part A, especially when part A does something asynchronously.

For example, if we want to fetch a file and then do something with it once it loads, we would make an asynchronous file call and then run our callback function once it loads.  If we're using a library like jQuery as a helper to make that call, our code might look something like this:

```
function getPageAndDoStuff(url, callback){
  jQuery.get(url, callback)
}


// We can declare a named function to do our stuff...
function justLogIt(html){
   console.log(html);
}
getPageAndDoStuff('/cart', justLogIt);
```

Alternatively:

```
// We can just declare an inline anonymous function to do that
getPageAndDoStuff('/cart', function(html){
  console.log(html);
})
```

The latter is a common design pattern for many types of tasks, but you'll note that the function we pass around doesn't have a name.  When something happens and we look at the call stack to see the order of functions that have been called to get us to that point, what name would we print?  Each unnamed function in our chain is simply called "(anonymous)"

Going back to your posted image, there is nothing in what you're showing that indicates a cause for serious concern.  The script file 'rocket-loader' is possibly pre-loading a few assets that it doesn't need to, so you may be able to boost your site's performance by tweaking whatever parameters 'rocket-loader' uses to be more selective in what you are pre-loading.